# Clone aws codecommit repo using chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, test-kitchen

How can i clone aws codecommit repo with chef recipe?

I tried installing AWS CLI and added credentials with codecommit access, then use chef’s git resource to clone the repo. but it fails with could not read Username for ‘https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com’ .

```
git "/home/ubuntu/lead_intake" do
  repository node[:app_name][:git_repository]
  action :sync
end
```

When tried to clone from the command line it works.

helps would be appreciated

Comment: What user did you add the credentials for? Remember that Chef is generally running as root so any creds would go in `/root/`.

Comment: Hello, the aws credential and .gitconfig are stored under, /root/.aws/

Comment: The credentials have to be in your git config, `/root/.aws/` wouldn't do anything.

Comment: i have  this in .gitconfig, [credential]
        helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
        UseHttpPath = true

Comment: and it works when I run the clone command locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have correct Access key ID and Secret access key in IAM -> users -> Security Credentials. 
Second, put [credential] helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@ UseHttpPath = true into .gitconfig file. 
Third, Both .gitconfig file and .aws directory should in the /root/ . Maybe this is the problem that you have. You put the .gitconfig in the /root/.aws/, which will make credential helper useless. Thus it is asking your Username/Password.

If you have done all the things above, it also fails, I suggest you to use ssh to clone the repository.  Follow this documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html

Comment: Thanks. It helped :)